# VBA Code to paste values in multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm trying to write a VBA Code to copy and paste multiple columns from a CSV file.
For the moment I have the following code:

```
Set thisWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set thatWB = Workbooks.Open("file_with_data.csv")
Set thatWS = thatWB.Sheets("table_with_data")
thatWS.Range("A2:X5000, Z2:Z5000, AC2:AC5000, AE2:AG5000").Copy
thisWS.Range("A4:X5002, Z4:Z5002, AC4:AC5002, AE4:AG5002").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

However, when i run it, i get the following error message:

```
Run-time error '1004'
That command cannot be used on multiple selections.
-> thisWS.Range("A4:X5002, Z4:Z5002, AC4:AC5002, AE4:AG5002").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: That error message seems self-explanatory to me. You can't use PS with multiple columns.

Comment: can we use Paste with multiple columns?

Comment: Yes, or you can use PS with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

As per the ***SJR*** suggestion:

```
Sub UseArray()
    For Each a In Split("A2:X5000,Z2:Z5000,AC2:AC5000,AE2:AG5000", ",")
        With Range(a)
            .Copy
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        End With
    Next a
End Sub
```

*(an alternative is to loop over `Areas`)*